# Does testing a PDO query in an if statement also run it?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I was checking up how to test for query success, and saw this method:

```
if($db->query(...)){

    //It was successful!

} else {

    //Something went wrong

}
```

But does this only check if the query would run successfully, or does it run the query and then return true/false? I'm assuming it is indeed run, but this brings me to the main question:

**Can I test if a query was successful in this way, and at the same time store the result set in a variable, like so?**

```
if ($result = $db->query(...)){

//something

}
```

Otherwise I'd have to run the same query once inside the if statement and then to store the results in a variable..

But yeah, basically, that's all I'm wondering. Thanks for all friendly help. :)

Comment: It runs the query and returns a response. If the query is successful the query is obviosly ran and the return is bool true, else it's false. There are some edge cases, I think, when it returns a false positive though.

Comment: Yeah, that's kind of what I figured as well, but I thought I might as well ask to be on the safe side. :)

Thanks for clearing that up though! ^^

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Functions and methods don't behave differently within a specific context.

If `$bd->query()` runs the query the behavior won't change if it's in a `if` statement.

So, yes it does run the query

you could try something like this to test your query

```
$result = $db->query();
if (is_null($result)) { 
    var_dump($result);
}
```

Comment: What about running $var = $db->query() inside or outside an if statement? Does it store the result set in the variable and return true simultaneously?

Comment: The thing is, $db->query() always does the same thing. It returns a result, which in your example is stored in $var.
An if checks if what you gave it is true or false. But if you give the if statement something different from true/false like a string, it'll use it's own process to determine if it's true or false. You should always try to give a if statement a true or false result, otherwise you could have some weird surprise and lose a lot of time debugging

Comment: Neither am I, however I get what you're saying about not making a mess out of the if statement. :)

The result set is a multi-dimensional array of course, but whether or not the if statement will read the variable as true or false based on the content it's given (not sure if the if statement will read the results or the boolean) I don't know. I can of course just check this, now that I know the statement is run anyway.

Thanks ^_^

Comment: You're welcome. I edited the answer if you want a code sample that is clear enough to test if the query is okay

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to validate a query before running it then you can try preparing it first like this:

```
$prepare = $db->prepare($sql);

// check if SQL compiled
if($prepare)
{
    // execute the SQL
    $execute = $prepare->execute();
}
```

Comment: Swell! Not what I was looking for right now, but definitely nice to keep in the back of my mind in the future. ^^